# How to use sample and seq in a dplyr pipline?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with two columns, low and high. I would like to create a new variable that is a randomly selected value between low and high (inclusive and equal probability) using dplyr. I have tried

```
library(tidyverse)

data_frame(low = 1:10, high = 11) %>% 
    mutate(rand_btwn = base::sample(seq(low, high, by = 1), size = 1))
```

which gives me an error since `seq` expects scalar arguments.

I then tried again using a vectorized version of `seq`

```
seq2 <- Vectorize(seq.default, vectorize.args = c("from", "to"))

data_frame(low = 1:10, high = 11) %>% 
    mutate(rand_btwn = base::sample(seq2(low, high, by = 1), size = 1))
```

but this does not give me the desired result either.

Comment: `data_frame(low = 1:10, high = 11) %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(rand_btwn = base::sample(seq(low, high, by = 1), size = 1))`

Comment: @bouncyball That works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the `rowwise()` pattern, I usually prefer to `map()` in `mutate()`, like:

```
set.seed(123)
data_frame(low = 1:10, high = 11) %>% 
  mutate(rand_btwn = map_int(map2(low, high, seq), sample, size = 1))
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#      low  high rand_btwn
#    <int> <dbl>     <int>
#  1     1    11         4
#  2     2    11         9
#  3     3    11         6
#  4     4    11        11
#  5     5    11        11
#  6     6    11         6
#  7     7    11         9
#  8     8    11        11
#  9     9    11        10
# 10    10    11        10
```

or:

```
set.seed(123)
data_frame(low = 1:10, high = 11) %>% 
  mutate(rand_btwn = map2_int(low, high, ~ sample(seq(.x, .y), 1)))
```

Your `Vectorize()` approach also works:

```
sample_v <- Vectorize(function(x, y) sample(seq(x, y), 1))

set.seed(123)
data_frame(low = 1:10, high = 11) %>% 
  mutate(rand_btwn = sample_v(low, high))
```

Comment: These are great solutions. What is your reasoning for avoiding `rowwise()`?

Comment: `rowwise()` creates an unnecessary grouping, and was meant (see `help("rowwise")`) to be used with `do()` that I'm even more wary of (package author recently stated he hasn't used `do()` in years, because there are usually clearer ways of doing things). That being said, it works. And it's even not less clear. And I'm all for whatever works